# Quick Sort implementation not working properly

Tags: c, sorting

I'm trying to implement Quick Sort in C, and I almost managed to do this, but there are still some problems I can't identify. The program seems to "forget" some number, which are in the wrong position.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void quicksort(int* vettore, int a, int b);
int partition(int* vettore, int a, int b);

int main() {
    int vettore[10];
    int contatore;
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("ESEMPIO DI IMPLEMENTAZIONE DI QUICK SORT\n\n");
    for(contatore=0;contatore<10;contatore++){
        vettore[contatore]=rand()%10+1;
    }
    printf("Vettore NON ordinato:\n");
    for(contatore=0;contatore<10;contatore++)
        printf("\nElemento n. %i: %i", contatore+1, vettore[contatore]);
    quicksort(vettore, 0, 9);
    printf("\n\nVettore ordinato:\n");
    for(contatore=0;contatore<10;contatore++)
        printf("\nElemento n. %i: %i", contatore+1, vettore[contatore]);
    printf("\n\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void quicksort(int* vettore, int a, int b) {
    int q;
    if(a<b){
        q=partition(vettore, a, b);
        quicksort(vettore, a, q);
        quicksort(vettore, q+1, b);
    }
    return;
}

int partition(int* vettore, int a, int b) {
    int i, j, pivot, temp1=0, temp2=0;
    pivot=vettore[a];
    i=a;
    j=b;
    while(i<j) {
        while(vettore[i]<pivot && i<j && i<b)
            i++;
        while(vettore[j]>=pivot && i<j && j>a)
            j--;
        if(i<j){
            temp1=vettore[i];
            temp2=vettore[j];
            vettore[i]=temp2;
            vettore[j]=temp1;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping though it in a debugger, line by line?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but I couldn't understand where the problem lies.

Comment: Shouldn't you do  `quicksort(vettore, a, q-1)` instead of `quicksort(vettore, a, q)` since pivot is already in correct position?

Comment: Actually it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: OFC it won't solve the problem. You're not swapping pivot into the correct position

Answer (score 0):

You're not swapping pivot into the correct position at the end of partition. The pivot is still at `vettore[a]`. You should swap `vettore[a]` with `vettore[i]` at the end of partition. Making a function as follows:

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
  int temp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = temp;
}
```

and using it for swaps will make you code much cleaner and easier to read. For example the `if(i<j)` block can be then modified as:

```
if (i < j)
{
  swap(&a[i], &a[j]);
  i++;
  j--;
}
```

**EDIT**

There are some mistakes above. I cleaned up your code. This works:

```
void quicksort(int* vettore, int a, int b) {
    int q;
    if(a < b){
        q = partition(vettore, a, b);
        quicksort(vettore, a, q-1);
        quicksort(vettore, q+1, b);
    }
    return;
}

int partition(int* vettore, int a, int b) {
    int i = a, j = b+1;
    while(true) {
        while (vettore[++i] < vettore[a])
            if (i == b) break;
        while (vettore[a] < vettore[--j])
            if (j == a) break;

        if (i >= j) break;
        swap(&vettore[i], &vettore[j]);
    }

    swap(&vettore[a], &vettore[j]);
    return j;
}
```

The most important thing is maintaining invariants. It becomes easier to reason about the code if you maintain invariants. Also, clean code is necessary for this. The invariants in the partition function above are:

- vettore[lo] is the pivot.
- vettore[lo+1]..vettore[i] are less than the pivot.
- vettore[i+1]..vettore[j-1] are unseen.
- vettore[j] to vettore[b] is greater than the pivot.
  The invariants are true before each iteration of the while loop and after the whole loop as well.

Comment: I tried, but the program crash sometimes, and when it does not, the array is not always sorted properly

Comment: should I still maintain this part as it was?<br/> `void quicksort(int* vettore, int a, int b) {
    int q;
    if(a<b){
        q=partition(vettore, a, b);
        quicksort(vettore, a, q);
        quicksort(vettore, q+1, b);
    }
    return;
}`

Comment: Logically, it should be `q-1` not `q`. `vettore[q]` is in the correct position. Once the pivot is in correct position, we should iterate to the left & right partitions without including the pivot. 
Also, in your case, it will result in infinite recursion if all elements are equal and less than pivot.

Comment: I re-wrote the whole function because it was a little hard to reason through your code.

Comment: How should I write the code whitout increasing "i" and decreasing "j" inside the while statement?

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is interested, i wrote a simplier version of the code:

```
int partition(int* vettore, int a, int b) {
int i, j, pivot, temp;
pivot=vettore[a];
i=a;
j=b;
while(i<j) {
    while(vettore[i]<pivot && i<b)
        i++;
    while(vettore[j]>=pivot && j>a)
        j--;
    if(i<j){
        temp=vettore[i];
        vettore[i]=vettore[j];
        vettore[j]=temp;
    }
}
temp=vettore[a];
vettore[a]=vettore[j];
vettore[j]=temp;
return j;
```

}